# Multi curl пропускает 5-10% ответов

Tags: curl, php

Задача следующая - имеется массив ссылок, нужно получить по ним html контент. Для решения задачи был выбран multi curl в виду его скорости работы. Проблема - некоторые страницы создаются пустые, страницы всегда разные, то есть при одном запуске страница А может быть сгенерирована, а при следующем - нет. И так происходит всегда, процент пустых примерно 5-10%. ниже 2 примера реализации.

---

**Пример 1**

```
   $mh = curl_multi_init();     
            $connectionArray = array();
            foreach($urls as $key => $url)
        {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
                $connectionArray[$key] = $ch;
        }
        $running = null;
        do
        {
            curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        }while($running > 0);

        foreach($connectionArray as $key => $ch)
        {
            //здесь получаю контент страницы
            $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
        }

        curl_multi_close($mh);
```

---

**Пример 2**

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
        $chs = array();

        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $chs[] = ( $ch = curl_init() );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
        }

        $running = null;

        do {
            curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);

            $info = curl_multi_info_read($mh);

            if (is_array($info) && ( $ch = $info['handle'] )) {
                // получаю содержимое загруженной страницы
                $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
            }                
        } while ($running);

        foreach ($chs as $ch) {
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
        curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Comment: Была подобная проблема, проверьте, возможно упираетесь в пропускную способность канала.

Comment: а не поделитесь данными по производительности. мне нужно получать и  парсить от 240к страниц в час. справится ли -curl с отправкой столько запросов ?

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте запросы на ошибки. Возможно слишком много запросов делаете одновременно. Для таких целей рекомендую вам библиотеку [mcurl](https://github.com/KhristenkoYura/mcurl)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 1):

Установите таймаут ожидания для $ch.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); // Таймаут соединения. 0 - для неограниченного времени
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // Таймаут ожидания. 0 - для неограниченного времени
```

Comment: Таймаут чтобы что?

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ на пример №2**
дело в том, что когда вы читаете ответ из curl_multi_info_read с помощью перебора(цикла), то вы можете пропустить ответ пока разбираете ответ.
curl_multi_exec  вернет $running == 0 и скажет я все выполнила, а ответ ловите сами.
Чтобы не пропустить точно ответ, надо получать ответ в цикле не только до  $running != 0 а еще до того, пока очередь оставшихся сообщений от curl_multi_info_read не станет равна нулю.
Получить эту очередь можно из ссылочной переменной второго аргумента функции curl_multi_info_read($m, **&$queued_messages**).
Это будет выглядеть так:

```
$running = null;
$queued_messages = 0;
do {
            curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);

        $info = curl_multi_info_read($mh, $queued_messages);

        if (is_array($info) && ( $ch = $info['handle'] )) {
            // получаю содержимое загруженной страницы
            $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
        }                
    } while ($running || $queued_messages > 0);
```